# Cifar-100 Dataset Error - Received a label value of 97 which is outside the valid range of [0, 10)

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn

getting this error when using the Cifar-100 dataset. I'm pretty sure I have the correct input shape and I have an output layer of 97, which are all the possible outputs in the dataset. What might I be doing wrong? Note: I am new to ML and Tensorflow, teach me some things please. :)

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  Received a label value of 97 which is outside the valid range of [0, 10).  Label values: 7 97 79 82 97 33 19 73 28 93 32 6 51 68 67 38 55 1 56 60 97 27 79 36 87 34 20 22 7 42 34 62
```

Thank you. Here is my code below. New to Tensorflow and I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#print(train_images[0])
#print("Network Accuracy: " + str(test_acc))
# plt.imshow(train_images[0], cmap=plt.cm.binary) #greyscale
# plt.imshow(train_images[0]) #neon
# plt.show()

cifar100_mnist = keras.datasets.cifar100

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = cifar100_mnist.load_data()

train_images = train_images/255
test_images = test_images/255
classes = [
    'apple', 'aquarium_fish', 'baby', 'bear', 'beaver', 'bed', 'bee', 'beetle',
    'bicycle', 'bottle', 'bowl', 'boy', 'bridge', 'bus', 'butterfly', 'camel',
    'can', 'castle', 'caterpillar', 'cattle', 'chair', 'chimpanzee', 'clock',
    'cloud', 'cockroach', 'couch', 'crab', 'crocodile', 'cup', 'dinosaur',
    'dolphin', 'elephant', 'flatfish', 'forest', 'fox', 'girl', 'hamster',
    'house', 'kangaroo', 'keyboard', 'lamp', 'lawn_mower', 'leopard', 'lion',
    'lizard', 'lobster', 'man', 'maple_tree', 'motorcycle', 'mountain', 'mouse',
    'mushroom', 'oak_tree', 'orange', 'orchid', 'otter', 'palm_tree', 'pear',
    'pickup_truck', 'pine_tree', 'plain', 'plate', 'poppy', 'porcupine',
    'possum', 'rabbit', 'raccoon', 'ray', 'road', 'rocket', 'rose',
    'sea', 'seal', 'shark', 'shrew', 'skunk', 'skyscraper', 'snail', 'snake',
    'spider', 'squirrel', 'streetcar', 'sunflower', 'sweet_pepper', 'table',
    'tank', 'telephone', 'television', 'tiger', 'tractor', 'train', 'trout',
    'tulip', 'turtle', 'wardrobe', 'whale', 'willow_tree', 'wolf', 'woman',
    'worm'
]
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(32, 32, 3)),
    keras.layers.Dense(150, activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(97, activation="softmax")
])

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5)

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)
print(test_acc)
# print(test_images)
prediction = model.predict(test_images)
answer = np.argmax(prediction[1])
print(classes[answer])
# print(train_images[0])
plt.imshow(train_images[1])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cifar100 dataset has 100 classes in its last softmax. So the last dense layer, in your model must have 100 as the value of units.

you can find below the updated code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#print(train_images[0])
#print("Network Accuracy: " + str(test_acc))
# plt.imshow(train_images[0], cmap=plt.cm.binary) #greyscale
# plt.imshow(train_images[0]) #neon
# plt.show()

cifar100_mnist = keras.datasets.cifar100

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = cifar100_mnist.load_data()

train_images = train_images/255
test_images = test_images/255
classes = [
    'apple', 'aquarium_fish', 'baby', 'bear', 'beaver', 'bed', 'bee', 'beetle',
    'bicycle', 'bottle', 'bowl', 'boy', 'bridge', 'bus', 'butterfly', 'camel',
    'can', 'castle', 'caterpillar', 'cattle', 'chair', 'chimpanzee', 'clock',
    'cloud', 'cockroach', 'couch', 'crab', 'crocodile', 'cup', 'dinosaur',
    'dolphin', 'elephant', 'flatfish', 'forest', 'fox', 'girl', 'hamster',
    'house', 'kangaroo', 'keyboard', 'lamp', 'lawn_mower', 'leopard', 'lion',
    'lizard', 'lobster', 'man', 'maple_tree', 'motorcycle', 'mountain', 'mouse',
    'mushroom', 'oak_tree', 'orange', 'orchid', 'otter', 'palm_tree', 'pear',
    'pickup_truck', 'pine_tree', 'plain', 'plate', 'poppy', 'porcupine',
    'possum', 'rabbit', 'raccoon', 'ray', 'road', 'rocket', 'rose',
    'sea', 'seal', 'shark', 'shrew', 'skunk', 'skyscraper', 'snail', 'snake',
    'spider', 'squirrel', 'streetcar', 'sunflower', 'sweet_pepper', 'table',
    'tank', 'telephone', 'television', 'tiger', 'tractor', 'train', 'trout',
    'tulip', 'turtle', 'wardrobe', 'whale', 'willow_tree', 'wolf', 'woman',
    'worm'
]
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(32, 32, 3)),
    keras.layers.Dense(150, activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="softmax")
])

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5)

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)
print(test_acc)
# print(test_images)
prediction = model.predict(test_images)
answer = np.argmax(prediction[1])
print(classes[answer])
```

Hope this helps